# DAE not exporting materials properly and slightly changes armature

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, armature, export, import

When I tried to export a model as a DAE file, the materials seem to get messed up.

Here's the original model, with all the materials' specular intensity set to 0:

[image]

Here's my export presets (there's a two link limit for us plebeians, so remove all spaces to see):

[image]

And here's what it looks like when I reimport it:

[image]

For some reason, all of the materials' specular intensity gets set to 0.5. I've imported DAE files that had their specular intensity set as 0 before. Also, all of the bones in the armature that previously had their head and tail very close to each other seem to be stretched downward. Is there any way fix this, or is this simply how Blender works at the moment?

[Here's a zip file.](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx5AYJ8irO53cFFGdWR4bWtDdUE/view) You might need to reattach the textures in the zip file to the blend file if you want to view the model properly. If you see the model properly, ignore that last statement. I named the exported file "FitPokeZenigame00 Fix.dae".

---

***Note:*** The Squirtle model does not belong to me. It was ripped from a video game known as Super Smash Bros. Brawl. All credit goes to Nintendo, Game Arts, Sora Ltd, etc.

Comment: See [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) about materials

Comment: Thanks.

What about the armature, though? Is it just stuck like that?

Comment: Can't comment much on that, I'm not an expert at rigging nor much into animation or armatures. Have in mind that all import/export formats are meant as **exchange formats**, not as a faithful save method. During the porting process some information is always bound be lost, corrupted or simply not supported.